# IBM DB2 .NET Core nuget package can't connect to server with licensing exception message

Tags: .net-core, db2

Installing to a console .NET Core 2.1 application the `IBM.Data.DB2.Core 1.2.2.100` nuget package and trying to connect to a connection string (Database=XXXX;UID=PIDXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Server=XXX.XX.X.X:PORT) receiving the below error.

> ERROR [42968] [IBM] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database
>   server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968 [IBM]
>   SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because
>   of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968

My licensing info seems to be correct.

[image: DB2Connect Licensing Information]

In [website documentation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Instructions_for_downloading_and_using_DB2_NET_Core_provider_package?lang=en) I'm supposed to copy the .lic file I installed for DB2Connect to the `%USERS DATA%\.nuget\packages\IBM.Data.DB2.Core\<version>\build\clidriver\license\` folder but still not working.

Comment: You have a v10.5 license file, but I believe the nuget delivers a Db2 v11.x client.  Either use a V11.x license file, or try the nuget-downgrade workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725613/db2-with-net-core-2-1

Comment: Thanks! Looks like downgrading the package works for the licensing issue but now I receive this. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlocpcv' in DLL 'db2app64.dll'.'

Comment: If you rebuilt, and still get this symptom, then downgrading is not a solution. If you have a support contract, refer to IBM support.

Comment: Downgrading resolved the licensing issue, but now I receive the above exception. I will create a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161054/ibm-data-db2-core-1-0-0-100-throws-system-entrypointnotfoundexception